# Why can't I install an older version of blender after uninstalling 2.8?

Tags: installation

So, I tried to download 2.8 yesterday and it didn't work because my graphic cards are old, so I tried to download 2.79 today and it says that there's a newer version installed and it doesn't download despite the fact I already uninstalled every Blender file in my computer before downloading.

Comment: Trying the portable version is so useful.  I use it to run both versions 2.79 and 2.8 without having to uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the 2.79 portable version on www.blender.org

Since it's just a .zip file, you don't have to install it, and the first time you open it, it will automatically set itself up in the OS

However I doubt your graphics card are a problem (Blender doesn't require a graphic card to run). You could try updating your drivers, or at least try the 2.80 portable version before downloading Blender 2.79

Comment: I think blender do require a graphics card to work.  The interface is very laggy when I use the internal (built-in) Intel card.

Comment: it's weird... I have a laptop without a GPU and it runs fine